# What is needed to run a webapp in IIS with absolute paths

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, iis-7

I previously made my "**Web Applications**" type of projects inside some individual directories
and have been making "Web Site" types (based on visual studio's project types") inside **IIS**.

*Although It should be a repetitive task but I want to know the most usual needed steps for doing so*

**What I need :**

Access to the media with absolute paths

**As an example**

I placed my project inside **"IIS Root folder/ProjectBase/Project"**
and convert that to Web Application via IIS.
It seems that I couldn't access to my stored media files within the Project Folder.
What is the exact problem in this case ? Is it related to **folder permissions** of the "Project Folder" ?

Also should I make the "ProjectBase" Folder also a virtual directory ?

*the program is running via cassini,
At first I want to have access to my Project based files via "absolute paths"*

**As a conclusion**
Having "Web Application" Type running with possibility to access to its files via absolute paths.

It should be an easy task for the Pros, but, anyway I'm in hurry and needed good-fast advice.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a file permissions issue.  You can resolve that by going through IIS and setting the permissions on the folders.  Grant read/write to the IIS user for that machine.  If you're actually writing anything back you may need to grant access to Network_Services as well.

Also you can look at adding a virtual directory to the website in IIS and point that to the actual physical directory on the box.   That has solved some file access issues for me in the past.

Comment: The Site is running just with clicking F5, What I mean is "It is running via Cassini", Do you thinks that this way I should set Permissions for IUSR ?

Comment: Second, I placed the web application inside IIS WebRoot and converted it to web app in IIS also, this way is a bit different with making it virtual folder in it's outside-IIS location,Also I think this way I couldn't access the media via absolute paths, Could I ?

Comment: Last is :I set Network Service permissions with All "read" forms, If you could help more will be glad to, also +1

Comment: Yeah, if you are running cassini via debug then you get a lot of the permissions automatically.  I had a similar problem when publishing to IIS7.  If you grant permissions in windows explorer, IIS can't always see them so you have to do it on the folder from in IIS.   Start with just giving it everything and if that works then you can pare down the permissions to what is necessary.

you could still access the files via absolute path but the plus of the virtual folders is you don't need to.  you can have a relative path in the application that points to the virtual folder and the virtual

Comment: folder points to the actual folder.

One other thing to consider that I just thought about is if the path is absolutely the same on your dev machine as on the web server.   You may want to change the absolute path to a UNC so there is no confusion on machine names causing a conflict.   or use server.mappath to set your absolute path name so everything stays in synch from dev to publish.  

Lots of options but first thing is to figure out if the issue is permissions or location.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I'm trying to get my desired result with a hit and miss approach